# How to Decrease the Font of a Text on LCDUI List and Form

Tags: java-me, lcdui

I have a LCDUI  List Screen Contains Title and Image from Rss File

```
          myList.append(Rss.getTitle(),Rss.getImage());
```

I have one Detail Form :on which i am able to display publish date and one hyperlink form Rss File

```
         m_itemForm.append(new StringItem("Pub Date:",videoItem.getPubDate()));
         final String URL = videoItem.getLink();
        stringItem = new StringItem("Link: ", "Set", Item.HYPERLINK); 
        stringItem.setText(URL);
        m_itemForm.append(stringItem);
```

Now i want to decrease the font of a text on both the Screens(List and Form)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately LCDUI List and Form do not allow an application to change the way they are presented. But you could use a [`CustomItem`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CustomItem.html). See [this article](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/customitem/) about it.

Comment: Can you send me the SampleCode, How  to Change Font?

Comment: Please, first read the article I mentioned to understand how to create CustomItems http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/customitem/ "Defining a custom item is a matter of subclassing CustomItem and implementing five abstract methods"